# Metro App periodically update Tile

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm having trouble working with `Live Tiles` in `Metro` apps.

Long story short, is it possible to create for example a **clock** app which shows clock in it's tile? even when it's not running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  A Tile cannot be updated often enough to represent a good clock.  Here are the [Notification Delivery methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh779721.aspx).